# utf8_bin vs. utf8_general_ci. which collation will provide faster performance in mysql table?

Tags: mysql, collation

I use '`id`' field - `char(22)` as a primary key for MySQL table.
this field is used only to filter unique ids when adding new users to the table.

for me it's not important whether to use `utf8_bin` or `utf8_general_ci` collation because case of letters doesn't matter and I use only English letters for id.

the only question is: 
which collation will provide faster performance?

the most common queries for my table are:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE ... IGNORE INTO TABLE mytable(id)
or
INSERT IGNORE INTO mytable(id)...
and 
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM mytable
```

now, I can't see any difference in performance since the table is not big, but what happens when the number of rows in my table exceeds 2 million?

will utf8_general_ci collation provide faster performance for the INSERT or LOAD IGNORE and SELECT COUNT queries?

Answer (score 5):

In general, `utf8_bin` is going to be at least as fast as `utf8_general_ci` because [it does not perform any processing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-binary-collations.html) on the binary data other than recognizing multibyte characters.

That said, the presence of an index on the `id` column and the fact that you are only looking to detect duplicates and not sort should mean that there will be absolutely no detectable difference. However, this is just an educated guess so I could be wrong (even though it does not look likely to me).